# what to check if an attribute must be present in request payload of Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, validation

I want to check if an attribute must be present in request payload(ie params)
In validator class. Should I use ***Presence: true*** or ***required: true***, during validation.

```
  validates :body_html, presence: true
```

or

```
  validates :body_html, required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a required validator in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) presence: true should do the trick. It may not be nil and it may not be an empty string if you are using the presence validator.

Answer (score 0):

In rails model, there is no `required` validation. There is `presence` validation to ensure field value must be present.

```
validates :body_html, presence: true
```

Using `presence` validation on field, if in request payload params field value is not present, then model throws error.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails a validator class is the class that provides the validation - not the model consuming it. [ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b738f1930f3c82f51741ef7241c1fee691d7deb2/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb#L63) is an example of a validator class.

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :body_html, presence: true
end
```

I believe you're confusing the presence validation with `optional/required` option for `belongs_to` which actually adds a presence validation.